# Facebook C# SDK installation from Nuget not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook-c#-sdk, nuget

Coding Platform: ASP.NET WebForms4.0 VB

Installed Facebook and FacebookWeb and when I run the application. I get this error

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Facebook.Contracts, Version=5.0.25.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de' or
>   one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with,
>   or it was delay signed but not fully
>   signed with the correct private key.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

What could be wrong?

Comment: do you have MicrosoftCodeContracts installed?

Comment: no. does Facebook.Contracts have a dependency? As of now I omitted code contracts. would that be a problem?

Comment: u shouldn't reference facebook.contracts.dll  i would recommend u to install Microsoft code contracts http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/

Comment: yep. i've read about it. sounds pretty good. but is it not better to eliminate dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the `Facebook.Contracts.dll` and `Facebook.Web.Contracts.dll`.
Working fine now.