# Facebook C# SDK - Which DLL to use?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I just downloaded the latest version of the Facebook C# SDK. I am migrating from the old Facebook Developer Toolkit.

I am using .Net 3.5 VS 2008. I will be using this SDK in Web and Console based apps. I noticed that the DLLs come in different flavors (Facebook, FacebookWeb, FacebookWebMvc). I am confused at to which one should I use for my Web and Console apps?

Also, what is the use for Facebook.Contracts.dll? Do I need to add it as a reference?

Any pointers?

**UPDATE:**

While trying to use the Facebook.Web.dll in my web app the following give me this error :"Precondition failed: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.AppId)":

```
FacebookWebClient client = new FacebookWebClient(token);
```

The error goes away if I change it to:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(token);
```

I am not sure why since there is VERY little documentation. So I guess I am going to stick to using the Facebook.dll for my Web app as well.

Comment: Just for my info, what is the difference between Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Facebook assembly for any project; it is the core assembly and the others depend on it. Use just Facebook for your console application. Use Facebook + FacebookWeb for a Web Forms project. Use Facebook + FacebookWebMvc for an MVC project.

Comment: And what about the Facebook.Contracts.dll? What is that used for?

Comment: That assembly is for code contracts (i.e. asserting that an argument is not null when constructing an object, etc.). Some people have issues with Facebook's version of them though. I've seen that you can remove references to that assembly and use Microsoft Code Contracts instead.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965071/facebook-c-sdk-installation-from-nuget-not-working

Comment: That clears it up for now. I will report back if I see any issues.